# Tag rename request: [theimpossibleastronaut], [nameofthedoctor], and [timeofthedoctor]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [theimpossibleastronaut](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theimpossibleastronaut), [nameofthedoctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nameofthedoctor), and [timeofthedoctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeofthedoctor) should all be reformatted to follow the standard convention of hypens in place of spaces. So, I would change them to [the-impossible-astronaut](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-impossible-astronaut), [name-of-the-doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name-of-the-doctor), and [time-of-the-doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-of-the-doctor) respectively.

Something else to consider is to drop "the" from the first tag, since other tags seem to be written that way (e.g. [day-of-the-doctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/day-of-the-doctor)).

The first two are only used once, so a simple edit will work (though I don't have the required reputation to do it myself). [timeofthedoctor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeofthedoctor) has a handful of questions, so it might be better for a mod to fix that using the merge tool.

Comment: Are those all single episode names?

Comment: @Kevin they are. It did seem odd to me that there were tags for single episodes, but that's a whole different issue

Comment: A side note, inclusion/exclusion of the `the` generally depends on if it's part of the official title or not - for example, [tag:the-matrix], [tag:the-walking-dead], etc

Answer (score 13):

Tags are supposed to be reasonably general, enough to make it worth one's time to favorite / follow them. Single episodes don't meet that criteria, and so they don't need their own tag. Accordingly, I have removed them from the questions.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you imagine if we had a tag for every single episode?